# Join on dm_db_index_physical_stats very slow

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, performance, fragmentation, microsoft-dynamics

I'm running a small query below in a MS Dynamics AX 2012 database and it runs more than 5 minutes which I had to cancel and it is showing `PAGEIOLATCH_SH` wait type. The database data file is 560GB and on SQL Server 2012 SP1.

```
SELECT TOP 1 A.avg_fragmentation_in_percent
FROM sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats(DB_ID(),NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL) A 
INNER JOIN sys.objects B
ON A.object_id = B.object_id
INNER JOIN sys.indexes C 
ON B.object_id = C.object_id AND A.index_id = C.index_id
INNER JOIN sys.partitions D 
ON B.object_id = D.object_id AND A.index_id = D.index_id
```

I checked resource monitor in the server for disk activity and the Read(B/sec) shoots up from an initial 23,000 to over 13,000,000 while the query is running and goes back down after the query is cancelled.

Any ideas what may be causing this?

Comment: Well you are scanning every index and heap in the database, at least part of each index in limited mode. The IO activity would be expected for the most part. That may look like a small query by line count but it does a good bit.

Comment: It is actually a longer query which I use to get the TOP N fragmented indexes filtered by the page count and fragmentation level. I simplified it to get the TOP 1 record only for the purpose of this post.

Answer (score 4):

The disk activity is high because it needs to pull your whole database into RAM to do its analysis. If you call `sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats` with fewer NULLs, it will be able to run your query on a subsection of the database, which will then run much quicker.

Sadly, your `TOP 1` isn't stopping it from doing all the calculations, as you're calling the main function with all those NULLs.

Comment: Thanks Rob. The query was used for this post only. It is actually a longer query to get TOP N indexes by fragmentation level filtered by page count in the database, hence the NULLs.

Comment: Ok, but you're asking for it to fetch all that info before finding the top one, so it has an awful lot of work to do.

Answer (score 4):

> *...it runs more than 5 minutes which I had to cancel and it is showing `PAGEIOLATCH_SH` wait type*

The `PAGEIOLATCH_SH` wait occurs when SQL Server is waiting for a data or index page that is not in memory to be fetched from persistent storage.

The [`sys.dm_db_index_physical_stats` dynamic management function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188917.aspx) running in `LIMITED` mode (the default) needs to read pages for the non-leaf levels of b-tree indexes and `IAM/PFS` pages for a heap that are not already in cache. For a 560GB database, this may well result in significant I/O.

> *It is actually a longer query which I use to get the TOP N fragmented indexes filtered by the page count and fragmentation level.*

You are probably reinventing the wheel here. Popular free index maintenance solutions include:

- [Ola Hallengren's Scripts for Index and Statistics Maintenance](https://ola.hallengren.com/sql-server-index-and-statistics-maintenance.html); and
- [Minion Reindex by the MidnightDBA team](http://www.midnightsql.com/minion/)

These will not necessarily make fragmentation assessment quicker, but they do offer highly-configurable pre-built solutions in wide use across the world. Minion Reindex in particular allows gathering of fragmentation information outside the maintenance window.